# how to compare mysql two datetime fields with two input datetime to avoid overbooking

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I am working on a parking booking project and want to ensure that no spot is overbooked for a particular time period. I am using the following syntax, but it is not working for me,

```
SELECT * FROM reservation WHERE 
`spot_id`='$id' AND
`Location`='$location' AND 
(`in` >= '$datein' OR `out` <= '$dateout' ) AND
(`in` < '$datein' OR `out` > '$dateout')
```

Please advise me.

I got the correct syntax as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM reservation WHERE spot_id='$id' AND Location='$location' AND (`in` between '$datein' AND '$dateout' OR `out` between '$datein' AND '$dateout' OR `in` <= '$datein' AND `out` >= '$dateout')
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. For your further questions, it might be beneficial for you, to know about this page: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help To receive help, it is necessary that your questions contain all necessary detail, but formating is also crucial, as people who might know the answer might not read your question if the formating is messed up. Good luck!

Comment: Incidentally, Event A overlaps Event B if Event A starts before Event B ends and ends after Event B starts.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, your logic is flawed.

After or equal to date `$datein` *or* before or equal to date `$dateout` signifies any date, ever.

```
(`in` >= '$datein' OR `out` <= '$dateout' )
```

And before `$datein` or after `$dateout` just confuses it further.

```
(`in` < '$datein' OR `out` > '$dateout')
```

Even so, what you want to do will not work the way you are currently attempting it. What if a spot was booked for a month and you want to check the middle week?

You need to normalise your data. E.g. An entry in a table for every individual day booked for each spot and query that table accordingly.